Error when trying to do multiturn chat with gemini-pro
This is the code I took from the API docs in order to start multiturn chat
model = genai.GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")
messages = [{'role':'user', 'parts': ['hello']}]
response = model.generate_content(messages) # "Hello, how can I help"
messages.append(response.candidates[0].content)
messages.append({'role':'user', 'parts': ['How does quantum physics work?']})
response = model.generate_content(messages)

But I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: Could not create Blob, expected Blob, dict or an Image type(PIL.Image.Image or IPython.display.Image).
Got a: <class 'google.ai.generativelanguage_v1beta.types.content.Content'>
Value: parts {
text: "hello"
}
I also tried using the send_message feature, but I got the same error after I tried to use send_message the second time.

As a simple modification, how about the following modification?
Modified script 1:
genai.configure(api_key=apiKey)
model = genai.GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")
messages = [{"role": "user", "parts": ["hello"]}]
response = model.generate_content(messages)
messages.append({"role": "model", "parts": [response.text]})
print("--- response 1")
print(response.text)

messages.append({"role": "user", "parts": ["How does quantum physics work?"]})
response = model.generate_content(messages)
print("--- response 2")
print(response.text)

Modified script 2:
As another modification, how about the following modification? Ref
import google.generativeai as genai

apiKey = "###" # If you use API key, please set your API key.


genai.configure(api_key=apiKey)
model = genai.GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")

chat = model.start_chat()


def get_chat_response(chat: genai.ChatSession, prompt: str) -> str:
    response = chat.send_message(prompt)
    return response.text


prompt = "hello"
print(get_chat_response(chat, prompt))

prompt = "How does quantum physics work?"
print(get_chat_response(chat, prompt))


Your code snippet works fine.
model = genai.GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")
messages = [{'role':'user', 'parts': ['hello']}]
response = model.generate_content(messages) # "Hello, how can I help"
messages.append(response.candidates[0].content)
messages.append({'role':'user', 'parts': ['How does quantum physics work?']})
response = model.generate_content(messages)

>>> print(response.text)
**Quantum physics** is a fundamental theory in physics that describes...

Is it possible you're using an old version of the SDK? The mixing of dictionaries and protocol buffers in messages shouldn't be a problem, but maybe was in an earlier version.
>>> genai.__version__
'0.5.1'


I also tried using the send_message feature, but I got the same error after I tried to use send_message the second time.

Please share your code. This works for me:
model = genai.GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")
convo = model.start_chat()

r1 = convo.send_message("hello")
print(r1.text)  # Hello there...

r2 = convo.send_message("How does quantum physics work?")
print(r2.text)  # **Quantum physics** is a fundamental theory in physics...

